# Desabilitando eol no bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, sourcetree

Como ferramentas de controle de versão eu utilizo o Bitbucket e o Sourcetree.
Só que parece que eles se perdem nas eol, dizendo que arquivos iguais são diferentes.
Me parece que a solução é desabilitar o eol no .gitattribute

Mas não estou conseguindo...

Alguem tem alguma ajuda?

abraços

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente isso acontece devido a diferenças como algumas plataformas ou programas de edição de texto trabalham os teminadores de linha.
Linux usa \n (LF = 1 byte) enquanto Windows por padrão usa \r\n (CRLF = 2 bytes).
Você deve padronizar a terminação no seu editor de código ou IDE (caso seja arquivo de código fonte) ou configurar para o git detectar automaticamente se deve ou não tratar as quebras de linha.
Ex. de como adicionar as configurações no git local: 
`git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Se preferir diretamente no arquivo *.gitattributes* :

```
# Declara arquivos que sempre terão terminadores de linha CRLF no checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf
# Declara arquivos que sempre terão terminadores de linha LF no checkout.
*.code text eol=lf
```

Veja outros detalhes aqui https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Sobre fazer esse ignore no bitbucket, parece que não tem jeito mesmo, pois não há nenhuma opção para adicionar essa diretiva.

Comment: Só funcionaria se fosse no github? Pq com o sourcetree no bitbucket sempre que eu copio arquivos iguais por cima dos originais do repositorio ele diz que são diferentes.

Comment: @GustavoEmmel o sourcetree é apenas uma interface para o Git ou Mercurial. Creio que se adicionar a diretiva no arquivo _.gitattributes_ ele tratará da forma esperadas as terminações de linha. O arquivo em questão deve ficar na raiz do repositório local.
Uma coisa que poderá acontecer é que na primeira vez que mudar a forma como trata o EOL você tenha que fazer um commit de _padronização_ para sincronizar os ambientes.